# Can I tell TypeScript that a function will only output null if the input is null?

Tags: typescript

I've got a function to strip null bytes from strings in input data:

```
export function stripNullBytes(str: string | null): string | null {
  return str?.replace(/\0/g, '') ?? null
}
```

Some of my input strings can be null, and some can't be (they're coming from a database). Similarly, some of the output strings can be null, and some can't be.

If I call `stripNullBytes` on one of the strings that can't be null (and so the output can't be null either), Typescript complains that `stripNullBytes(cantBeNull)` is not of the right type (it's `string | null` instead of `string`).

Is there a way I can tell TypeScript this fact about my function? I can use the bang operator (`let str: string = stripNullBytes(cantBeNull)!`), but is there a more elegant way that removes the possibility of me making a mistake?

Comment: So you actually want the function type's to be `(str: string) => string | (str: null) => null`, rather than `(str: string | null) => string | null`? Have you tried [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)?

Comment: Didn't know about those, but I just tried them and they work. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your function's type is `(str: string | null) => string | null`, which means a string input could give null output and vice versa. Instead, it sounds like you want `(str: string) => string | (str: null) => null`, where a string output always gives a string output and a null input always gives a null output.

This can be achieved with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) as follows:

```js
export function stripNullBytes(str: string) : string;
export function stripNullBytes(str: null) : null;
export function stripNullBytes(str: string | null): string | null {
  return str?.replace(/\0/g, '') ?? null
}
```

Note that the third and final definition isn't actually part of the overload list; consumers can only call the function through one of the first two definitions. This means that you *cannot* call `stripNullBytes` with something that's `string | null`. If you wanted to retain this you have to repeat that as an overload, but ensure that the more specific definitions appear first:

> [The compiler] looks at the overload list and, proceeding with the
> first overload, attempts to call the function with the provided
> parameters. If it finds a match, it picks this overload as the correct
> overload. For this reason, it’s customary to order overloads from most
> specific to least specific.